Export full chain of site with openssl similar to what Chrome would do
When using Chrome (and likely other browser) I can check the certificate chain:

From there I can export the full chain as Base64-encoded ASCII, certificate chain

Then the file obtained is something like:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDqzCCAzGgAwIBAgISBNJAnQnZ18furlY6bSIhUWVTMAoGCCqGSM49BAMDMDIx
...
GdWDvkyg3wNvGaH94nrgRdvyFRcAc8Vekw8mjyGYAw==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEVzCCAj+gAwIBAgIRAIOPbGPOsTmMYgZigxXJ/d4wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw
...
VQD9F6Na/+zmXCc=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFazCCA1OgAwIBAgIRAIIQz7DSQONZRGPgu2OCiwAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw
...
emyPxgcYxn/eR44/KJ4EBs+lVDR3veyJm+kXQ99b21/+jh5Xos1AnX5iItreGCc=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

The question is, how do I get the exact same result with openssl?
How to view certificate chain using openssl is related to this but doing:
echo | openssl s_client -connect serverfault.com:443 -showcerts

This only return 2 certificate blocks, not the full chain. And it has other parts, I just want the BEGIN -> END CERTIFICATE.
Bonus question: how do you call the BEGIN -> END CERTIFICATE part in technical terms?

Found more details and an answer from: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368123/how-to-extract-the-root-ca-and-subordinate-ca-from-a-certificate-chain-in-linux
openssl doesn't return root certificate
But @Hakan54 created a really useful tool: https://github.com/Hakky54/certificate-ripper
crip export pem --url=https://stackexchange.com --combined=true

This would give the same wanted output than Chrome.

openssl s_client doesn't print the trust anchor (the root CA certificate) as that's assumed to be installed, or passed as a file.
To print the chain without the root, simply pass the above through awk to filter:
$ echo | openssl s_client -connect serverfault.com:443 -showcerts 2>/dev/null | awk '/BEGIN/ {} /BEGIN/, /END/ { print }'

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

